# unpair dual-mode bluetooth device in uwp application

Tags: windows, bluetooth, device

1. use Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher to discover the device
2. Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync([address]) to get Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice
3. call Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(....)

because the device is a dual-mode bluetooth device, after pairing, there are same two device names I can see in the Windows Bluetooth list.  And after calling the UnpairAsync api, I can only unpair the BLE device.

Is there a way to unpair both devices?

Comment: Do the same but for BluetoothDevice class.

Comment: I have tried, but for BluetootheDevice, the API UnpairAsync returns AlreadyUnpaired

Comment: It looks like device has 2 MAC: BLE and Classic. Once you know only BLE MAC you can unpair BLE only. To find out Classic MAC you need to enumerate paired Classic devices and then unpair it. If the device has only one MAC then try to use Legacy Bluetooth API (not sure it can be done from UWP). I recommend to try with Bluetooth Framework. Pair with device from your app and then use BluetoothManager demo app to unpair the device.